# Can't delete or rename wiki article in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, confluence

After migration from Confluence to Azure DevOps I can't delete or rename articles containing dots.
I already tried this [api to delete an article](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/796447/cant-erase-a-page-from-wiki.html) , but it didn't work.

**Error:**
`The wiki page operation failed with message : The page name cannot start or end with a "." and cannot contain the following characters /, \. Parameter name: pageName`

Comment: change name to not contain those and try again?

Comment: "I can't delete or **rename** articles"

Comment: right, care to rename the question in this case?

Comment: @lossOfIdentity Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try azure devops cli to see if this works.

To edit a wiki page, enter the `az devops wiki page update` command.

```
az devops wiki page update --path
                           --version
                           --wiki
```

To delete a wiki page, enter the `az devops wiki page delete` command.

```
az devops wiki page delete --path
                           --wiki
```

For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/add-edit-wiki?view=azure-devops&tabs=azure-devops-cli#edit-and-delete-wiki-pages).